# Jquery div slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used quite a few jquery sliders like bxslider, wooslider etc. but they all slide images. is there any particular slider that can slide a div that contains some contents? if so, please give me some examples. and, what will happen if i try a div instead of an image with wooslider/bxslider?

Comment: bxSlider is absolutely an HTML content slider. I've used it for complex structures on several occasions. Did you try?

Comment: @isherwood no, i didn't. what about wooslider, mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I have really only used Bootstrap libraries to do this. The template can be customized to how you want it, and it includes different ways to present text onto of every slide. If you want header tags, paragraphs or even a list. Controls can be changed, the Bootstrap controls that comes with Bootstrap aren't the best, they are kinda the basics. I recommend using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and customizing the controls yourself. However you can not have the same text that is fixed when the slider is moving in the background. You must create a div outside the slider div.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Best example is on the mophie battery (mophie.com) website, using Bootstrap